# Giving an object multiple parents with Ancestry gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry

I have an object `Person` that has two parent `Person`s.  I want to be able to receive an array of `Person` objects when I do `my_person.parents` (currently undefined).  I'm currently using the ancestry gem, which seems to limit you to a single parent.  Is there any way that I can accomplish what I want with the gem, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's essentially a many-to-many relationship (Person has and belongs to many parents). You need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship from Person to itself, with a join table.

See here for an example: [ActiveRecord relationships for a join table linking two records of the same table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957169/activerecord-relationships-for-a-join-table-linking-two-records-of-the-same-tabl)

Comment: If I chose to go this way, I'd have to do validation myself to ensure that there are no cyclical relationships and such.  I'm holding out hope for a quicker solution, but thanks for this fallback option.

Answer (score 0):

Ancestry only supports 1 parent.

The parents are stored in a string of type

```
ancestry = "/grandparent_id/parent_id"
```

So there is only 1 slot for a parent. see https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/issues/94

I'm thinking ancestry may not be the best solution for you. May want to try out colsure trees or another plugin